# Generating all possible combination of the elements of integer vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector, combinations

I have an integer vector of size "n".

```
e.g.
std::vector<int> vec;
vec.pushback(0);
vec.pushback(1);
vec.pushback(2);
vec.pushback(3);
....
```

Now i want to generate all possible combinations of size = {0, 1, 2, ... , n}.

please keep in mind that 
{0, 1, 3} is not equal to {3, 1, 0} or {1, 0, 3} or {3, 0, 1}

Please help me if you have an idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation

Comment: @Mat Thank you for your reply, nexr_permutation will generate fixed size combinations, But how i can repeatedly apply it for for different size.

Comment: Look at the links in the "Related" section on the right. All this has been asked and answered, you need to pick the pieces and make them fit your scenario.

Comment: @user986789 you seem unwilling to do any research on your own. The solution involves combinatorics as well as permutations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include <vector>

    std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, std::vector<int> v)
    {
        for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
        {
           os << *it << ",";
        }
        return os;
    }

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> v;
   v.push_back(1);
   v.push_back(2);
   v.push_back(3);
    do {
       std::cout << v;
    } while (std::next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()));

}
```

As per @JamesKanze's comment, this can only work if the vector is sorted to begin with, so if you have an unsorted vector, you should call `std::sort` on it first.

Looking at [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation), it says:

> Transforms the range [first, last) into the next permutation from the set of all permutations that are lexicographically ordered with respect to `operator<` or `comp`.

You can see it in action [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1FoeoN%240)

Comment: You might mention that this only works if the list is sorted to begin with.

Comment: @Tony  Thank you for your reply, i see it generate fixed size combinations, But how i can repeatedly apply it to generate combinations of different sizes, means 1, 2 and 3

Comment: I think the simplest would be to call the function again every time your vector size changes.

Comment: Just resize it to the number you want.